# How to use the callback function in ReactJS Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a `form` with several fields. And I am doing the validation as well.

So on the `onSubmit` it calls to a function `handleSubmit` and there I am doing the validation.

So if there are any empty fields, they will produce an error and will be shown below each field.
If there are NO errors, it will be route to the `/register-success` component.

Now my problem is, if there are any empty fields when I click on `Register` button, those respective errors are being set using `setErrors`. But it is not being updated to the `errors` variable right after it is being set.

So unlike in `class components` I could have used a `callback` function with `setState` but in `hooks` I saw a workaround to use `useEffect`. It is working, but now I don't know how to `redirect` the page to `/register-success` within the `useEffect` because I can't do it within the `handleSubmit` because of the `errors` are not getting updated even after the `setErrors`

So How can I do the `callback` operation using `react` `hooks` or how can I redirect the page within the `useEffect`?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Register() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setValues((values) => ({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {

      // RIDERECT TO THE /register-success  ==============================
    } else {
      // alert("Errors found");
    }
  }, [errors]);

  const validateForm = (values) => {
    let allErrors = {};
    if (!values.name) {
      allErrors.name = "User name is required!";
    }
    if (!values.phonenumber) {
      allErrors.phonenumber = "Phone number is required!";
    }

    if (!values.email) {
      allErrors.email = "Email address is required!";
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
      allErrors.email = "Email address is invalid!";
    }

    if (!values.password) {
      allErrors.password = "Please provide the password!";
    }

    if (!values.confirmpassword) {
      allErrors.confirmpassword = "Please confirm the password is the same!";
    }

    return allErrors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validateForm(values));

    
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="container login-container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 login-form-2">
            <h3>Register to post your ad</h3>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Name *"
                name="name"
                value={values.name || ""}
              />
              {errors.name && (
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {errors.name}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                name="phonenumber"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Phone Number *"
                value={values.phonenumber || ""}
              />
              {errors.phonenumber && (
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {errors.phonenumber}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                name="email"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Your Email *"
                value={values.email || ""}
              />
              {errors.email && (
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {errors.email}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="password"
                name="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password *"
                value={values.password || ""}
              />
              {errors.password && (
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {errors.password}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Confirm Password *"
                name="confirmpassword"
                value={values.confirmpassword || ""}
              />
              {errors.confirmpassword && (
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {errors.confirmpassword}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              {/* <Link to="/register-success"> */}
              <input type="submit" className="btnSubmit" value="Register" />
              {/* </Link> */}
            </div>
            <div className="form-group btnForgetPwd">
              By clicking "Register" you are agreeing to our{" "}
              <Link target="_blank" to="/terms-and-conditions">
                <a
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    textDecoration: "underline",
                    fontStyle: "italic",
                  }}
                >
                  Terms and Conditions
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6 login-form-1">
            <div className="login-logo">
              <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n7oTvU/logo_white.png" alt="" />
            </div>

            {/* Register  */}
            <h3>Already a member? Login</h3>

            <div className="form-group text-center pt-5">
              <Link to="/login">
                <input type="button" className="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const validationErrors = validateForm(values)
    if(Object.keys(validationErrors).length > 0) {
      setErrors(validationErrors);
      return;
    }
    // REDIRECT TO THE /register-success  ==============================
  };
```

If you've got errors redirection won't be triggered and component will re-render with errors updated

Comment: Thank you for the idea. So how can I know redirect the page on the button click?

Comment: const history = useHistory() at the start of your component then history.push('/register-sucess') when needed